# Maximum allowed concurrent requests threshold was breached

Tags: javascript, post, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am working on retrieving data from an XML API. In order to render a result to the screen I have to call one endpoint to get a list of data, then I have to map through the list of items and call a second endpoint for each returned item. The first request goes through successfully; however the rest of the requests seem to be called concurrently. This is leading to about 90% of the requests coming back with the following error:

```
Maximum allowed concurrent requests threshold(10) was breached
```

My back end function that calls the API endpoint takes in XML as a string and converts the response to JSON. Here is the code:

```
export function newSoapRequest(options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "",
    headers: {},
    xml: "",
    timeout: 10000
}) {
    const {
        method,
        url,
        headers,
        xml, // soap envelope as string
        timeout
    } = options

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
            method: method || "POST",
            url,
            headers,
            data: xml,
            timeout
        }).then((res) => {
             resolve({
               res: {
                    headers: res.headers,
                    body: XML.parse(res.data), 
                    statusCode: res.status,
                }
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            if(err.response) {
               reject(err.response.data)
            } else {
               reject(err)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Here is the code where I am calling the API from the map function

```
resortList.map(async (resort) => {
            let resortXML = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dae="DAE"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><dae:DAEGetResortProfile><!--Optional:--><dae:AuthID>GWAYUAT</dae:AuthID><!--Optional:--><dae:EndpointID>${resort.WeekEndpointID}</dae:EndpointID><!--Optional:--><dae:ResortID>${resort.ResortId}</dae:ResortID></dae:DAEGetResortProfile></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`
            await newSoapRequest({method: "POST", url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: resortXML, timeout: 10000})
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
```

As far as I know the response is sent from the newSoapRequest function and then the connection is closed. When I am using async await inside the map function the map function should wait until the request is completed and the connection is closed before processing the response and then running for the second time. Could this issue be related to the map function it's self? Or is my newSoapRequest function not closing the connection properly?

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.prototype.map` function does **NOT** awaits until an async function ends. That is the reason all the items are being called concurrently.

To avoid that, you can use this approach:

```js
const numbers = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => i + 1);
const callback = async n => await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(`${n} * 2 = ${n * 2}`), 10));

async function sequentialAsyncMap(arr, predicate) {
  const result = [];
  for (const item of arr) {
    result.push(await predicate(item));
  }

  return result;
}

sequentialAsyncMap(numbers, callback)
  .then(console.log);
```

Example with [callback-chunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callback-chunk) package (Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package):

```js
const chunk = require('callback-chunk');
const callbacks = resortList.map(item => () => newSoapRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: sampleHeaders,
  xml: `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dae="DAE"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><dae:DAEGetResortProfile><!--Optional:--><dae:AuthID>GWAYUAT</dae:AuthID><!--Optional:--><dae:EndpointID>${item.WeekEndpointID}</dae:EndpointID><!--Optional:--><dae:ResortID>${item.ResortId}</dae:ResortID></dae:DAEGetResortProfile></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`
}));

const items = await chunk(callbacks, 10, console.log);
```

Comment: I tried wrapping the map in a Promise.all function. Now more of the requests are completing successfully, but it is still only about 30% of the total requests I am making.

Comment: @Alex `Promise.all` will not make the requests sequential, just awaits to all of them finish.
As another solution, you can make batches of requests, requesting 10 at time, and then getting the results. There is a npm package that does that: [callback-chunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callback-chunk). (Disclaimer: I made this package).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed your suggestion and updated my map function. But every time I run the chunk function I get a console error that says "callback is not a function". Here is my map function:
`resortList.map(resort => {
 let resortXML = "soap data"
 callbacks.push(() => new Promise(resolve => {
  newSoapRequest({method: "POST", url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml:resortXML, timeout: 10000})
  .then((res) => {
   resolve(res.body)
  })
 }))
})`

Comment: and then I am calling the chunk function with:
`await chunk(callbacks, 10, console.log)`

Comment: also when I console.log callbacks it shows me that it is indeed an array of functions

Comment: @Alex I edited the question to show an example of the package usage. By your comment it should work, I don't know what happened, I tested here and didn't have any problem with an Array of Functions.

Comment: Thanks. I think what was happening was it was losing the execution context for the functions when passing to a third party module. I was playing around with the code and whenever I logged out callbacks it showed an array of null values. But the array that I was passing it was an array of functions. I was able to create something that works sort of similar though and it works great!